# How to replace quote ( `”` ) with normal quote (`"`)

Tags: python, file, encode

I have some large content in a text file like this:

```
1. name="user1” age="21”
2. name="user2” age="25”
....
```

If we notice I have this ( `”` ) special type of quote here at end of each word.

I just want to replace that quote ( `”` ) with normal quote (`"`)

**Code:**

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('myfile.txt',encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print "str  text : ",line
    a = repr(line)
    print "repr text : ",a
    x = a.replace(u'\u201d', '"')
    print "new  text : ",x
```

**Output:**

```
str  text :  1. name="user1” age="21”

repr text :  u'1. name="user1\u201d age="21\u201d\n'
new  text :  u'1. name="user1\u201d age="21\u201d\n'
```

but its not working. What I am missing here?

**Update :**

I just tried this:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('one.txt')
for line in f:
    print "str  text : ",line
    y= line.replace("\xe2\x80\x9d", '"')
    print "ynew  text : ",y
```

and it is working now.

Still I want to know what was wrong with  `x = a.replace(u'\u201d', '"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is the **repr** of the line, which *does not* contain the char `”`, but contains the string `\`,`u`,`2`,`0`,`1`,`d`.

So changing `a = repr(line)` to `a = line` will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks you very much!